# Login Failed for user after application worked

Tags: asp.net

I am busy working on a Asp.Net web application (Created an empty project) and I created a user Sign Up page which will return data from the user and insert it into MS Sql Server 2016.

At first the application could insert User details into the Users table successfully. But after I closed and re open the application I am getting an error that says

"Login failed for user/My PC name"

I don't know what is causing this error because the application worked the first time but after I re opened the app, it gives me that error.

Please note that I can successfully connect to MS Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: Is the error message coming from ASP or from SQL?

Comment: The error is coming from ASP